# Android User Location returning 0.0 for latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android

I have a class object which retrieves the users latitude and longitude. In my UI thread I create the object in the onCreate method that creates the Activity:

```
userLocation = new UserLocation(this);
```

Here is the class snippet:

```
public UserLocation(Context mContext) {
    //Pass parameter to class field:
    this.mContext = mContext;
    //Fetch the user's location:
    fetchUserLocation();
}

public void fetchUserLocation() {
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager:
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates:
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Manage the data recieved:
        makeUseOfLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}


    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates:
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}

private void makeUseOfLocation(Location location) {
    //Split the data of the location object:
    userLatitude = location.getLatitude();                      
    userLongitude = location.getLongitude();                    

}

/**
 * @return userLatitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    return userLatitude;
}

/**
 * @return userLongitude
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    return userLongitude;
}
```

Now back in the main thread, when a button is pressed, the latitude and longitude is collected:

```
    // GET THE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE OF THE USER:
    currentLatitude  = userLocation.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = userLocation.getLongitude();
```

Now for say I launch the application, if I press that button right away, the values received are 0.0 for both latitude and longitude.

But, if I launch the application and wait 4-5 seconds then press the button, correct values are then received.

Can anyone tell me the cause of this behavior?

I noticed it when I was writing a method that when the user launches the application if a field is null, then collect latitude and longitude. Well this in turn returns the unfavored 0.0 value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me the cause of this behavior?

Well yes - presumably when it's showing 0, 0, `onLocationChanged` hasn't been called yet - because the location isn't known immediately. You've requested that the location manager calls you back when it knows the location - that's not the same as getting the location immediately.

If you don't want to report the location to the user before it's known, you should remember whether or not `onLocationChanged` has been called (or potentially even *when* it was last called, to avoid showing stale data).

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Well if I pass a refrence to my UI class and call a method that handles that data once onLocationChanged has been called it could work. The only issue is, it would make that call everytime the location is changed. I only want updated info when the user presses the button, do you know of a workaround?

Comment: @VesicaPiscis: I'm not sure what you mean at all, to be honest. But it sounds like you either want to always be listening for information *or* you want to wait until the user clicks the button, then register the listener and *only update the UI* (and unsubscribe) when you're called back. Without knowing more about the app, it's hard to say which is most appropriate. You just need to think about how to integrate the asynchronous nature of location updates into your app.